# Compute the cosine of a vector

Tags: glsl, shader

I'm learning about shader, and I've come across the following GLSL code:

```
vec3 color = cos(vec3(.5,.3,.4));
```

How do I compute the cosine of a vector `vec3(.5,.3,.4)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *GLSL* most of the functions are overloaded and the argument can be a vector. Operations and functions may operate component wise. In case of [`cos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/cos.xhtml), the cosine is computed for each component of the vector and the result is stored in a new vector:

The expression statement

```c
vec3 color = cos(vec3(.5,.3,.4));
```

can be read as

```c
vec3 color = vec3(cos(.5), cos(.3), cos(.4));
```